# Backbone.js RequireJS Mixin

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have create a mixin component using requirejs like so:

```
define(function() {
    'use strict';

    var MyClass = function () {
        console.log('Hello World');
    };

    return {
        doSomething: function () {
            var m = new MyClass();
            return m;
        }
    }
});
```

My question is that is it better to write this mixin where the return is a function that can be included without accessing the returned object?

So the above would be rewritten like:

```
define(function() {
    'use strict';

    var MyClass = function () {
        console.log('Hello World');
    };

    return function doSomething() {
        var m = new MyClass();
        return m;
    }
});
```

And then when you include this module, you can then just call `doSomething()` versus having to include the module and access the method like `myModule.doSomething()`.

I know that either way is acceptable, but just wanted to get an opinion on implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on agreed conventions in your project as well as on code structure. The second example probably seems more **SOLID** to me since every module or class should be just single responsibility. Retrurning object notation could tend to more functions on the module returning level. Just a thought though.

Comment: Thank you! The current implementation of my module is in the first example, but as I thought about the code throughout the weekend, I wasn't "happy" with it and like the second methodology better.